# How to send request on facebook sdk 3.0 Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i am working on facebook sdk 3.0 in android and need to send request to friends 
and my code is :-

private void sendRequestDialog() {

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("message",
            "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
            Logout.this, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    Logout.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    Logout.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values
                                .getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    Logout.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    Logout.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

when i am clicking on **Send button Toast is coming for request send but request is not coming to friends** and no notification coming to that friend but i need this i am no getting what is problum please help me;)

Comment: i have the same issue i also try with uid in params and requst sent toast is there but no request comes in friend profile..if you find any solution then please tell..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add facebook id of your friend in Bundle params.

`params.putString("to", uid);`

Comment: but how i will get id of all friends?

Comment: i am not getting how to get uid?

Comment: i have the same issue i also try with uid in params and requst sent toast is there but no request comes in friend profile...

Answer (score 1):

```
private void sendInviteDialog(String uid,final int position) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("to", uid); 
    params.putString("message", "Please try my app"); 
    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            MessageUtil.showMessage( "Request cancelled", true);
                        } else {
                            MessageUtil.showMessage( ResourcesUtil.getString(R.string.network_unavailable), true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            MessageUtil.showMessage( ResourcesUtil.getString(R.string.friend_request_sent), true);
                        } else {
                            MessageUtil.showMessage(ResourcesUtil.getString(R.string.request_not_successful), true);
                        }
                    }   
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            })
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: is any additional permition required i am just using app id in my app?

Answer (score 1):

That is because your app is in Sandbox mode.Disable sandbox mode.It works